# Check if an element has a label in Selenium/WebDriver (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

I have the following HTML code:

```
<input id="session_remember_me" name="session[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label for="session_remember_me">Remember me</label>
```

I want to check if the `session_remember_me` field has label `Remember me`
How do I check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Ruby, but in Java, you could just do the following :

```
boolean isLabelPresent = true;
try {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='session_remember_me']"));
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    isLabelPresent = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it in Ruby:

```
  def isElementPreset?(type, selector)
    begin
      @driver.find_element(type, selector)
      true
    rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
      false
    end
  end

  assert isElementPresent?(:css, "label[for='session_remember_me']")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this with XPath:
`//form/div/div/div/span/input[@id='session_remember_me']/parent::span/parent::div/parent::div/label[@for='session_remember_me'][contains(text(),'Remember me')]`
and just check if such an element exists.